# How to change css of element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have defined a CSS property as

```
#myEltId span{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

On clicking a button, I want to remove its border.

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
  // How to fetch all those spans and remove their border
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use:

```
$('#button1').click(
    function(){
        $('#myEltId span').css('border','0 none transparent');
    });
```

Or, if you prefer the long-form:

```
$('#button1').click(
    function(){
        $('#myEltId span').css({
            'border-width' : '0',
            'border-style' : 'none',
            'border-color' : 'transparent'
        });
    });
```

And, I'd strongly suggest reading the API for `css()` (see the references, below).

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Thanks David.I tried the same but it was not working for me because of some silly mistake..sorry my bad

Comment: No worries; glad to have been of (some, small) help anyway. Even if only to verify your original approach.

Answer (score 5):

If you will use this several times, you can also define css class without border:

```
.no-border {border:none !important;}
```

and then apply it using jQuery;

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
        $('#myEltId span').addClass('no-border');
});
```